# how does random() work with array's index?

Tags: java, random

could someone explain this code please ..
i want to know is the random number going to be between 1 and 6?
or this step generates random numbers and initialize it to frequency[1+generator.nextInt(6)]++;
if am wrong could someone explain the last statement ..

```
frequency=new int[7];

public void rollIt() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    for(int i=1;i<frequency.length;i++)
        frequency[1+generator.nextInt(6)]++;
}
```

Comment: It builds a histogram, basically. If the RNG is kinda uniform and you run the function often enough, you will get approximately the same numbers in each cell of the array, meaning that each number is equally likely. But the ``new Random()`` should not be inside this function, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [`nextInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) is called with `6` as a parameter, it will return a random number between `0` and `5`.  When `1` is added, that translates the range to between `1` and `6`.

That number between `1` and `6` is treated as an index into the array `frequency` for the array access expression.  Then the `++` operator increments whatever element was chosen by the array access expression.

At the end, the `frequency` array holds frequency counts for each roll, and the index serves as the number rolled while the number value in the element is the frequency.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
  Int[]frequency = new int [x];
    For (int i=0; i<frequency.length; i++){
    frequency [i] = generator.nextInt(6)+1
    }
```

When you instantiate the size of the array for x you can ask the user how big the array needs to be and set their answer to x. It's just a little extra thing